# Access custom theme settings from within views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I have a few custom theme settings which so on my themes settings page.. this all works fine and as expected.

I now need to create a view that gets that custom theme setting. I can't find anything on how to do this.

I have installed the views php module and I know this `theme_get_setting('setting_name')` is what i used to get the theme settings in my `template.php` file.

Any help with this will be much appreciated.

Regards
C

Comment: is this on the right track: `$conf ~ developer/globals.php ~ Array of persistent variables stored in 'variable' table.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for other people who come across this here is the answer:

`<?php print theme_get_setting('setting_name'); ?>` works using the `views_php` module

It doesn't show in the views preview but does in the actual page load.

Thanks goes to @sheena_d for helping with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the views Theme attribute in the basic settings of the view. You can override it with writing the views template file with the corresponding output i.e. row style,etc. and customize the themeing in it.This is the basic functionality of the views.You have to place this file in the themes folder which is your enabled theme.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't quite understand where that is, can you please give me a little direction on where to find that in views

Comment: is this on the right track: `$conf ~ developer/globals.php ~ Array of persistent variables stored in 'variable' table.`

Comment: You can edit the view then under Basic settings there is the theme infront of it click on the information link and then click on the output which you want to get  i.e. row style,etc. then click on the link like row style and copy the link  code that is displayed and then made a file and its name is to be as written infront of the link like rowstyle and save it in the themes you have enabled then you can click on the rescan templates button then your file is applied.

Comment: Thanks, I have all of that part sorted.. But how do I get the variable from the database? it's not a field or node data... it's a custom variable set in the variable table in the databse. That is the issue I have. Sorry if it was confusing.

Comment: Are you making the view for the custom data.If you want to add the custom fields of your module in the view then you can use the hooK_views_data to add the field in the views arguments or fields or filter,etc for reference see this for drupal 6 http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!docs!docs.php/group/views_hooks/6 .For drupal 7 see this link below:- http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7